# "I will make what I learn..." or "I will make what I learnt..."?

Tags: grammar

> I will make what I learn during this internship available to anyone in need through Facebook.

Should I use learn or learnt if I wish to imply that it is a future internship?

Comment: If the learning is already in the past at time of speaking you *must* use ***learnt***. But if the learning (and the internship) lie in the future most native speakers would use present tense ***learn*** - past tense is "acceptable" because the learning would obviously be in the past by the time the information is made available on FB, but explicitly "future" *(**will learn, will have learnt**)* forms would normally only be used by non-native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a more complicated question than you might expect.  English is quirky in that we choose certain verbs, or conjugate verbs, based on the *perspective* of the sentence.

As FumbleFingers mentions in his comment, you would use *learnt* (or *learned*) if your are done learning.  You can also use the past tense if you imagine speaking from some point in the future where the learning is *complete* and ready to share.  Otherwise you would say *learn* if you imagine yourself in the current moment, where you have *yet to learn* what you intend to share.

All of these are grammatically fine.  Each has a slightly different *nuance*:

> I will take the birdhouse that I **make** with my children and put it in the yard.
>
> I will take the birdhouse that I **made** with my children and put it in the yard.
>
> I will take the birdhouse that I **have made** with my children and put it in the yard.